# JQuery Sortable + Bootstrap - 1st column to last column - item vanishes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to work out how to use JQuery Sortable with Bootstrap v3.

I have 3 columns and I want the list of items in column 1 to be dragged and dropped into column 3 - column 2 will contain some buttons to move all items back and forth.

The functionality works however while dragging, the item vanishes behind the middle column.

I've tried setting Z-Index of the column and the items being moved but still no joy.

Here's a basic fiddle...[JsFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/oor7ej9e/)

```js
$(".sortableList").sortable({
  cancel: ".fixed",
  connectWith: '.sortableList',
  distance: 6,
  opacity: 0.5
});
```

```css
#available {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  height: 200px;
}

#selected {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  height: 200px;
}

.item {
  margin: 1px;
  background-color: #bebebe;
}

.sortPlaceholder {
  opacity: 0.25;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="sortContainer" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5 scroll-vertical">
      <div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative">
        <div id="available" class="sortableList" runat="server">
          <div class="item">Item 1</div>
          <div class="item">Item 2</div>
          <div class="item">Item 3</div>
          <div class="item">Item 4</div>
          <div class="item">Item 5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="<<" onclick="removeAll()" />
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value=">>" onclick="addAll()" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5  scroll-vertical">
      <div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative">
        <div id="selected" class="sortableList" runat="server"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a div with `overflow:hidden` right inside the `scroll-vertical` . you need to remove that or change it to visible

then if you need to scroll inside the containers, add overflow-y auto to `.sortableList`

see snippet below

```js
$(".sortableList").sortable({
  cancel: ".fixed",
  connectWith: '.sortableList',
  distance: 6,
  opacity: 0.5
});
```

```css
.sortableList  {
    overflow-y:auto;
}
#available {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  height: 50px;

}

#selected {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  height: 200px;

}

.item {
  margin: 1px;
  background-color: #bebebe;
}

.sortPlaceholder {
  opacity: 0.25;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="sortContainer" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5 scroll-vertical">
      <div style="overflow: visible; position: relative">
        <div id="available" class="sortableList" runat="server">
          <div class="item">Item 1</div>
          <div class="item">Item 2</div>
          <div class="item">Item 3</div>
          <div class="item">Item 4</div>
          <div class="item">Item 5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="<<" onclick="removeAll()" />
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value=">>" onclick="addAll()" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5  scroll-vertical">
      <div style="overflow: visible; position: relative">
        <div id="selected" class="sortableList" runat="server"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The overflow: hidden is a work-a-round for another issue.  I need to be able to scroll vertically through the list of items...but setting overflow-y: scroll causes a problem whereby the item being dragged causes the containing div to infinately scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

I made a library to turn bootstraps grid into a drag and drop thing and maintain its responsiveness.
https://rosspi.github.io/gridstrap.js/